# Web application Loading time issue at the beginning( in Angular 6)

Tags: angular, angular6

Its about a big fat web application. When I run the app locally it starts perfectly with a very little loading time. I have already committed my project to the server. When I run it via using the IP address of the server at that time its taking too much time to start the application.The loading time in this case is more.

[image: This is the screenshot of the waterfall of network]

I have used two images in the landing page. Those are logo.png and bgloginscreen.png.Both are inside the /assets/images folder.I have used the  bgloginscreen.png inside css file and logo.png in the img tag in the html file as shown below.

```
      .r-col {
   flex: 1 1 40%;
   max-width: 40%;
   background-image:url(../../assets/images/bgloginscreen.png);
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width:60%;
     }

   <img src="assets/images/logo.png">
```

According to  the waterfall shown in the image, the loading time is so high just because of these two images. I am not able to find out the real reason behind the delay in loading.

[image]
  Here another issue is in the network tab the request method for  bgloginscreen.png is not picking this image from the path provided i.e  assets/images. logo.png is picked from the correct location.
My main goal is to reduce the loading time of my app while starting. I have mentioned all those which seems problems to me.
If this much information in not enough please ask me. Thank you

Comment: How heavy are your images? Consider switching png to jpg for background image and try switching logo to svg. Other than that there is nothing to say more unless you provide us with the example where your problem can be reproduced

Comment: size of the images are 21 and 16 kb .
Can you give me any solution how to load images asynchronously

Comment: Images should not block the thread. That’s why I ask for a minimal reproduction

Comment: sorry but i am not getting what r u asking for. can u please explain  what is minimal reproducion in your point of view.
and yes i have converted to svg and jpg.but no change.

Comment: minimal reproduction is a project / page where one can **reproduce** your issue. You can describe it as much and as good as you can but it will never replace / it can never be better than something one can see and debug

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve